How to obtain a map $BU(n-1) \to BU(n)$ in the calculation of $H^*(BU(n), \mathbb Z)$?
I'm trying to follow the proof that $H^*(BU(n), \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[c_1, \dotsc, c_n]$, from Wikipedia.
It contains the following paragraph:

There are homotopy fiber sequences
$$S^{2n-1} \to BU(n-1) \to BU(n).$$
Concretely, a point of the total space $BU(n-1)$ is given by a point of the base space $BU(n)$ classifying a complex vector space $V$, together with a unit vector $u$ in $V$; together they classify $u^\perp \subset V$ while the splitting $V=(\mathbb {C} u)\oplus u^{\perp }$, trivialized by $u$, realizes the map $BU(n-1)\to BU(n)$ representing direct sum with $\mathbb {C}$.

I don't understand that, how exactly is the map $BU(n-1) \to BU(n)$ defined? How do I turn a $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb C^\infty$ into an $n$-dimensional subspace?
From the description, I could imagine that there exists a $S^{2n-1}$-fiber bundle
$$S^{2n-1} \to E \to BU(n),$$
which for each $n$-dimensional $V \subset\mathbb C^\infty$ is the unit sphere $S^{2n-1} \subset V$. Then one has a map $f: E \to BU(n-1)$, given by
$$(u,V) \mapsto u^\perp \subset V \subset \mathbb C^\infty.$$
Guess. $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.
Is that true? I'm not completely sure how to see that. I think $f$ is a fiber bundle (i.e. locally a product), and the fiber of $f$ over $W \subset \mathbb C^\infty$ consists of all vectors $u \in \mathbb C^\infty$ of length $1$, which are not contained in $W$. So this is basically $S^\infty \setminus S^{2n-3}$. Is that contractible?

Such a bundle exists, and $E$ is homotopy equivalent to $BU(n - 1)$, but you're overcomplicating things. Since you write $BU(n)$ instead of $\mathrm{Gr}n$, you can just appeal to a functorial construction of $B$ for your map. Alternatively, you can also write down an embedding $\mathrm{Gr}{n - 1} \to \mathrm{Gr}_{n}$. All of this is standard, and you should be able to find it in most texts that treat the relevant notions, though probably not on wikipedia.

As Ben mentioned in the comments, there are various other ways to write down a map $\mathrm{BU}(n-1) \to \mathrm{BU}(n)$ but in this post I want to demonstrate that your analysis is pretty point-on. All of what I'm writing is just a reiteration of material covered in a course held by Markus Hausmann (Proposition 5.32 on p. 72).
Let us denote by $S(\gamma^n)$ the sphere bundle of the tautological bundle on $\mathrm{BU}(n)$, the total space has elements $(V, v)$ with $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ and a unit vectors $v \in V$. Furthermore, let us take the model $\mathrm{BU}(n) \simeq \mathrm{Gr}_n^{\mathbb{C}} = \operatorname{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$.
Proposition. There is a homotopy equivalence $S(\gamma^n) \simeq \mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb{C}}$.
Proof 1 (Sketch). This is essentially your argument. One can check that the map $$S(\gamma^n) \to \mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb{C}}, (V,v) \mapsto \langle v \rangle^{\perp}$$ is a fiber bundle. I personally haven't checked this and would suppose that there is some hands-on work involved that requires fiddling around with point-set topology. Once we believe this (and you seem to do so in your post), we compute the fiber over $W \in \mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb{C}}$ to be $$ S(W^{\perp}) = \{v \in \mathbb{C}^{\infty} : |v| = 1, \ v \perp W \} = S^{\infty}(W^{\perp}) \cong S^{\infty} \simeq *.$$ The missing component to your reasoning is that we take the unit vector inside the still $\infty$-dimensional vector space $W^{\perp}$ which is $S^{\infty}$ again.
By the long exact sequence $S(\gamma^n) \to \mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb C}$ is a weak homotopy equivalence but one can prove that these guys can be endowed with a CW structure, so we conclude by Whitehead. $\square$
Proof 2. We can also go with a hands-on approach and abuse that there is a lot of room to move around the coordinates. Morally, this is similar to the $S^{\infty}$ considerations, as a classical proof of its contractibility is the ability to move around coordinates!
Anyhow, we define two maps:

$\Phi : S(\gamma^n) \to \mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb{C}}, \ (V,v) \mapsto \langle v \rangle_V^{\perp} = \{x \in V : x \perp v \}$,
$\Psi : \mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb{C}} \to S(\gamma^n), \ W \mapsto g_*(\mathbb{C} \oplus W, (1,0))$ where $g: \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{\infty} \to \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ is the (non-canonical) isomorphism you expect.

We claim that these are mutual homotopy inverses.

$\Phi \circ \Psi$: It sends $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ to $0 \oplus W \subseteq \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{\infty} \xrightarrow{g_*} \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ (so it shifts coordinates!). Via a straight-line homotopy  from $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{\infty}}$ to $\mathbb{C}^{\infty} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ inside $\mathrm{Gr}_n$ we can realize $\Phi \circ \Psi \simeq \mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Gr}_{n-1}^{\mathbb{C}}}$.
$\Psi \circ \Phi$: It sends $(V, v)$ to $g_*(\mathbb{C} \oplus \langle v \rangle^{\perp}, (1,0))$ Now, via a straight-line homotopy one can homotop this to $g_*(0 \oplus V, (0,v))$ and another straight-line homotopy shifts the coordinates back.

This finishes the proof. $\square$
Remark. Note that secretly, $\Psi$ is already one of the ways to write down a map $\mathrm{BU}(n-1) \to \mathrm{BU}(n)$. Postcomposing $\Psi$ by $S(\gamma^n) \to \gamma^n \to \mathrm{BU}(n)$ yields that map which is succinctly given by
$$ \mathrm{BU}(n-1) \to \mathrm{BU}(n), \ W \mapsto g_*(\mathbb{C} \oplus W).$$ The subtlety here is really to remember the linear isometric isomorphism $g_*$ which one should not forget!
